Global Model with Person ID
Is i am going to build a machine learning model for a group of 100 people, for example to classify them into successful/unsuccessful students, can i add their person ID (e.g. 1~100) as an additional feature vector?
Expect to obtain better performance?

I assume you have data about their grades, and possibly attendance? You should not include the student ID as a feature in your model here for a couple of reasons:

It probably isn't correlated with the outcome (student success), unless the ID was assigned by GPA, or something like that. It shouldn't provide any information that can be used to explain success.
If you included the ID, then perfectly overfit your training data, possibly with a highly non-linear technique like a decision tree, or a deep neural network, your model will be useless for labeling an unseen student (student 101, for example). Here you can read a little about overfitting.

If your goal is to explain what makes students successful, consider only including those features that you suspect have a relationship with "success". Also consider how each type of algorithm decomposes, or explains importance. For example, a linear model could provide a linear-additive decomposition, with p-values describing feature significance, and a logistic regression (for your classification problem) is an extension of linear regression. A tree model or ensemble can provide an estimate for "feature importance" based on how often a specific feature was used to split a node. Also consider reading about Shapley Values.
